# Simulate fullscreen

Tags: c++, winapi

I've seen an application that simulates a fullscreen application by removing the title bar and the window borders. I've done some research and found getWindowLongPtr() for that.

Now my question: How can I find and identify the application and get the appropriate window handle? How can I distinguish multiple instances of the application (running from different locations on disc)?

---

Just to make "simulate" more precise. If you make an application go fullscreen and you click on a different monitor, it minimizes itself. If the application runs in a window and you click on a different monitor, the window is not changed. If you remove the borders of the window and position it on the left or right monitor, you can still work with the other monitor without minimizing the application. Still it looks like the application running fullscreen on one of the monitors.

---

As an example: you can set Eve (www.eveonline.com) to fullscreen and windowed mode. In fullscreenmode you can not click on a second monitor without Eve minimizing itself. In window mode you can. There are tools like evemover that allow you to setup your window on one monitor, looking like fullscreen, but being in window mode. That's what I want to archieve. Evemover actually provides some of it's source code, that's why I know that removing the border and setting the position is done using the Win32-API with setWindowLongPtr and setWindowPos.

Comment: How do you mean simulate it? The way to make a fullscreen win32 app IS to create the window borderless, without a titlebar and make the the fullsize of the screen.

Comment: There's another way - select fullscreen as option when initializing DirectX

Comment: Could you give an example context? Are you looking at a game-like behavior? Or (for lack of a better description), a Macintosh expose'-like behavior (full screen overlay that can be dismissed easily). Will the minimize-on-lose-focus be used heavily?

Comment: (edit to above) Does it trap the mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many applications use divergent and confusing applications of the phrase "fullscreen".

A fullscreen application simply - occupies the full screen area.
DirectX applications can request a fullscreen exclusive mode. The advantage of this mode to DirectX applications is, with exclusive access to the (full) screen they are then allowed to change the resolution, bit depth etc, as well as gain access to vertical sync synchronized hardware buffering where the screen surface is 'flipped' between display intervals so that 'tearing' does not occur.

Anyway, the windows desktop understands 'fullscreen windows' - windows that occupy the full area of a monitor and have no non client elements. When windows like this are created, things like desktop gadgets and task bars automatically hide themselves. Modern games have come to call this mode 'fullscreen windowed'.

Back to your question: 'FindWindow' is the API used to discover other applications windows. Getting the path to the application that created the window is much harder. GetWindowThreadProcessId can get you the process id of the owning process. OpenProcess will get you a handle that you can pass to QueryFullProcessImageName (implemented on Vista and above) to get the full path to the process.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are refering to applications like window aggregators, that 'plug in' to the system and act from outside the application.

Look at the code for the freeware app PuttyCM (for aggregating Putty (SSH) shell windows as tabs). IIRC, it ensures that the Window pointer passed to the application has the flags already set.

On applications running from different places, you will probably need some way of identifying it - registry entries / install log etc.